# How to check if some metric has a particular type of geodesics?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, symmetry, geodesics, de-sitter-spacetime

For instance, we want to know if cylindrically symmetric de Sitter-type spacetime has an axial geodesic.

This is the metric I am interested in

$$ds^2= \cos^{\frac{4}{3}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3 \Lambda}}{2} \rho \right)\left(dt^2 -dz^2 \right) -d\rho^2 - \frac{4}{3\Lambda} \sin^2 \left(\frac{\sqrt{3\Lambda}}{2}\rho \right) \cos^{-\frac{2}{3}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3\Lambda}}{2}\rho  \right) d\phi^2.$$

Comment: Propose a form for the geodesic and see if you can make it satisfy the geodesic equation?

Comment: Thank you, it's just brilliant and really simple. I feel so stupid not noticing that :)